# How to nest MVC site within an MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In visual studio, I create an MVC 4 app.  I then publish it.

I then create a subfolder called SubApp, and copy the same MVC app to the subfolder.

I then add a link on the home page of the Main App, to the sub app.

For example, the link looks like this:

```
<a href="/SubApp" title="Go to Sub Site">Go To Sub Site</a>.
```

I then run the app, and click on the link.

I then get the error: The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.(the sub directory).

How should I be linking to the SubApp?

Greg

Comment: did you try removing the / from /SubApp? Did you try instead: ~/SubApp?

Comment: Yes, I have tried.  It gives the same message.  It appears to be trying to list out the contents, instead of serving up the page.

Comment: Do you have an index page at all?

Comment: No, but I could.  I just don't know how that works with MVC.

Comment: MVC doesn't have an index page, so I don't know how to refer to it.

Comment: You should use [Areas](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project), that's like deploying a project to subfolder.